# Batch script to copy all files but those in a list

Tags: batch-file

I am looking to write a script to copy all files but those contained in a list. I am a new at this but found the opposite of what I want...

```
@echo off
set src_folder=c:\Source\
set dst_folder=c:\Destination
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (list.txt) Do xcopy /S/E/U "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
```

I am backing up a folder full of files but need to skip a few as they are unimportant to me.

I thought something like this would work. but I must have made an error...

```
@echo off
set src_folder=c:\Source\
set dst_folder=c:\Destination\
xcopy /S/E/U "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%" /exclude for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (c:\list.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
xcopy .... /exclude:list.txt
```

see

```
xcopy /?
```

from the prompt for documentation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mangoo I got it figured out so for anyone needing it...

```
@echo off
set src_folder=c:\source
set dst_folder=c:\destination
xcopy "%src_folder%" "%dst_folder%" /exclude:c:\List.txt
```

This also looks for only certain aspects in the list so if you want to exclude all copies, you can type just (2) and it will not include any files with that entry. (This caused me a problem at first.